# Windows placed under dock (plank) in XFCE

Tags: xfce, plank

I'm trying to get a non-compositing desktop to be functional in Ubuntu 16.04. I installed the dock Plank, but I have the problem that windows appear underneath the dock. Windows should never overlap with the dock unless I put them there. I had an identical problem in openbox.

Is there some way to fix this?